# Newbie; Running Rankings database

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. One with results and one with athletes. When I run it lists every result from every athlete. How do I just get the fastest time from each athlete? In the example below I just want Reed Brown fastest time.

```
id  place   athlete_id  grade   team_id             time    event
126 3      Reed Brown   11      TEXAS               4:01.99 1600m
127 1      Reed Brown   11      Southlake Carroll   4:07.17 1600m
95  1      Reed Brown   11      Southlake Carroll   4:07.17 1600m
128 2      Bryce Hoppel 12      Midland Senior      4:15.12 1600m
96  2      Bryce Hoppel 12      Midland Senior H    4:15.12 1600m
```

Comment: need what your current query is and maybe a pic of your tables

Comment: SELECT performances.id,
       performances.place,
       performances.athlete_id,
       performances.grade,
       performances.team_id,
       performances.time,
       performances.event
FROM performances
order by time asc

Comment: which result do you want to show? 
`athlete name  1 - Time`  `athlete name  2 - Time` and following, or just the time?

Comment: @Alex Let me know if the below answer worked for you. I updated.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
Select per.*
From performances per
Inner Join
(
  Select athlete_id, MIN(time) AS fastesttime 
  From performances 
  Group By athlete_id
)per1
On per1.athlete_id=per.athlete_id
Where per1.fastesttime=per.time
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Now I need to figure out how it works. Any good online resources you recommend?

Comment: w3 schools is usually pretty good for SQL. Also, if you are able to, make sure to select answer as accepted and upvote. Thanks.